# jquery fade in, image over image

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I have a 800x500 image.  The bottom two quadrants have edits to the graphics that I want to fade in.

If the whole image consisted of
AB
CD

C & D are what will be covered up after 10 seconds with two images that fit in the bottom quadrants.  I started of with display:none; thinking that the fadein() takes care of that, but I've messed something up.

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CwgyW/)  I used different images but the sizes are correct.

style.css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #000;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display:inline;             
}

.bottom-left {
    position:absolute;  
    top:250px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}

.bottom-right {
    position:absolute; 
    top:250px;
    left:400px; 
    display: inline;

}
```

The page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- STYLE SHEETS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<!-- JQuery * QTip Plugin at the bottom --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#bottom-left').fadeIn(10000);
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<image src="images/NoAlertFull.png">
        <span class="bottom-right">
                <image src="images/Alert-red.png">
        </span>
        <span class="bottom-left">
                <image src="images/Alert-yellow.png">
        </span>     
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adressing the span by id, instead of by class: change the selector to

```
$('.bottom-left').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

bottom-left is your class name . so use it with a dot

```
 $('.bottom-left').fadeIn(1000);
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/CwgyW/5/

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

If you try to get an element using the id, use #

```
Ex : $("#myDivId").fadeIn(3000);
```

If you try to get an element using the class name, use a dot

```
Ex : $(".myCSSClassName").fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the id selector `#bottom-left` instead of the class selector `.bottom-left`.

Also, jsfiddle has its own document outline, you don't paste a whole page in, just the body content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/CwgyW/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#bottom-left').fadeIn(10000);
```

should be

```
 $('.bottom-left').fadeIn(10000);
```

`#` is for selecting by id

`.` is for selecting by class